# arrayWithContentsOfFile and arrayWithContentsOfURL nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, plist

When I call [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:], I get nil.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:className relativeToURL:[self JSONDataRecordsDirectory]];
return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [fileURL path]]];
```

Alternatively, I also get nil when I call:

```
[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:]
```

The results of all my files are in JSON here:
https://gist.github.com/neverbendeasy/03d047a6789b0ae14e1f

When I check the fileURLs, the data is there.

What am I missing?

Comment: what about fileURL? is it non-nil? looks like you're working with local file, so you should use +[NSURL fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:] or +[NSURL fileURLWithPath:] methods instead

Comment: @Russian Yes, fileURL is non-nil (it has the JSON output in the gist above). I tried fileURLWithPath and still got a nil array. :(

Comment: wait, are you trying to initialize the array with contents of JSON file? +[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:] can only be used with plists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't load a JSON file using `NSArray arrayWith...`. That method can only load a plist file with an array as the root.

If your file is a JSON file you should use:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
if (jsonArray) {
    // do something with jsonArray
} else {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't load JSON from %@: %@", fileURL, error);
}
```

This assumes the top level of the JSON file is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURL's

```
+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path
```

or

```
+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL)isDir
```

instead of

```
+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
```

when working with the local filesystem.

Comment: Tried both and still get nil array.